# Docker Image to run on any flavor of Linux

Tags: docker, teamcity, dockerfile

I am pretty new to Docker. I have gone through entire documentation though but can not figure out how I can create my own image that will wrap my JAVA source.
Another things I am looking fir is to be able to run my JAVA application on any flavor of Linux. This is why I am here looking for Docker.
My application is a selenium Automation with chrome. I want chrome to run in headless mode(no GUI). 
Can anyone please let me know how I can do this.
Summarizing the things:

1. Run chrome in headless mode
2. Application should be able to run on any flavor of Linux

For this, how I can build my Image ?

Comment: Please ignore the 3rd point. Its a noise.

Comment: for 1 have a look at Selenium, http://www.chrisle.me/2013/08/running-headless-selenium-with-chrome/

Comment: I have managed to do so using Xvfb. 
All I want to make docker image which will run my app on any flavor of Linux  after installing and running  Xvfb, java and maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but can not figure out how I can create my own image that will wrap my JAVA source.

You create an image which provides an execution environment, not data.
Your data (your java sources) can be mounted at runtime in order to be visible by the container.

```
docker run -v /path/to/your/sources:/path/to/your/sources <yourImage>
```

For the image itself, you can start by looking at [`sminnee/docker-selenium-xvfb`](https://github.com/sminnee/docker-selenium-xvfb), which provides a Selenium RC worker, running in XVFB. It will record the entire XVFB and save it as a movie file

Comment: Will this image run on any flavor of Linux ?

Comment: Yes, provided that Linux kernel is at least 3.14 or more recent.

Comment: Thanks.. Its a Great help !

Comment: One quick question, how I can run application using this build though ? You might think its silly question but I am strangling with this.

Comment: It is best to isolate another app execution in a separate container.

Comment: It will be two images then.
Currently I run my application on Ubuntu 14.04 as:
1. Terminal 1: Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24
2. Terminal 2: mvn clean verify -f <path to pom.xml>
This mean my application needs Xvfb to run first to support headless mode.
How I can accomplish this using the image you suggested ?

Comment: @DDeshmane I don't know Selenium enough to answer that. You can ask a new question (with a link back to this one) and a tag selenium, in order to get a more precise answer.